# Bug in Number or BigInteger and BigDecimal (or alternatively in the API documentation of those)?

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

According to the specification of `Number.longValue()` the method should...

> *Returns the value of the specified number as a long. This may involve rounding or truncation.*

However, the `BigInteger` (and `BigDecimal`) overrides this method and returns the 64 low bits of the integer part of the number it represents. From the docs of `BigInteger` for example:

> *[...]if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned.[...]*

I claim that either "*This may involve rounding or truncation.*" doesn't say *anything* about what the method actually *should* return, or, there is a bug in implementation or documentation.

Would you agree, or do I have a mistake in my reasoning?

---

Example code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger i = valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);

        // Result: Long.MAX_VALUE, just as expected.
        Number n1 = i;
        System.out.println(n1 + " -> " + n1.longValue());

        // I expect to get the "rounded" value Long.MAX_VALUE
        Number n2 = i.add(ONE);
        System.out.println(n2 + " -> " + n2.longValue());

        // I expect to get the "rounded" value Long.MAX_VALUE
        Number n3 = i.multiply(TEN);
        System.out.println(n3 + " -> " + n3.longValue());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9223372036854775807 -> 9223372036854775807
9223372036854775808 -> -9223372036854775808
92233720368547758070 -> -10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording *"This may involve rounding or truncation"* appears in the javadocs for the `longValue()`, `shortValue()`, `charValue()` and `byteValue()` of [`Number`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), so it is clear that "truncation" is intended to *include* loss of significant *high order* bits in some cases.

The problem really is that the term "truncation" conventionally means loss of lower order bits.  (That's how I remember it from my numerical analysis course, 30 years ago.  And [Wikipedia agrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation).)

By contrast, the [JLS 5.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.3) describes the same process (when narrowing integral primitive types) as follows:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T.

So yes, I agree that the javadoc is incorrect.  Submit a bug report.

**NOTE**

I had originally deleted this because I thought my suggestion to submit a bug report was probably futile (based on my past experience with documentation bug reports).  But @aioobe *has* submitted a bug report ... (Bug ID: [7000825](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7000825))

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of `BigInteger.longValue()` continues with:

> Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as *return a result with the opposite sign*.

This redefines (or clarifies) the behaviour defined by `Number.longValue()`. This is fine, although it is sometimes misleading. For example `java.util.Set` redefines the behaviour of the `add` method (by constraining duplicates). If you pass a `Collection` you may expect it to hold any values, but the concrete implementation has redefined this behaviour.

**Update:** I checked how does `Long.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).intValue()` behaves. And it prints -1. So I'd assume that by "round or truncate" is just a possibility, regarding floating point numbers. Otherwise the `Number` class leaves the way of conversion entirely to implementors. So yes - it does not tell anything about it. I wouldn't say it is that bad, but it is certainly misleading.

Comment: I disagree. The documentation of `add` in `Collection` explicitly states that *"Collections that support this operation may place limitations on what elements may be added to this collection. In particular, some collections will refuse to add null elements, and others will impose restrictions on the type of elements that may be added."*

Comment: @aiobee - ok, the collection example isn't the best one. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your question, how is this any different from the garbage you get whenever you try and represent a number outside the bounds of a particular numeric type?

```
final Number n = Long.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(n + " -> " + n.intValue());
```

prints

```
9223372036854775807 -> -1
```

Do you want the API to tell you that you'll get invalid output if you pass invalid input?

Comment: Most of all, I would like `BigInteger.longValue` to return `Long.MAX_VALUE` if the value it represents is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Alternatively I'd like the documentation of `Number.longValue` to say something like *"returns some long, representing this value"*

Comment: Maybe it should say *"This may involve rounding or **binary** truncation"*

Comment: I've never heard the term "binary truncation". You have a reference on that? (btw, I wouldn't want to *remove* ordinary truncation from the description, as this is used by all floating point `Numbers`.)

Comment: What I'm getting at with binary truncation is anything to the left of the lower order 64 bits being removed.  Yes decimals may be rounded or numerically truncated, but what you expect to happen is statistical truncation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_%28disambiguation%29).  I'd probably argue that *"Returns the value of the specified number as a long"* captures whats happening, you're starting with 65 bits and only using the left most 64.